# Issue with PCIe WiFi adapter and Apple AirPort Express

Tags: wireless-networking, mac, router, pci-express

I've been using Apple devices for a long time. My WiFi router is AirPort Express and it has worked great with iMac (even though iMac was located far from the router). Now I build my new PC and bought a cheap (10$) PCIe adapter (TP-Link with 1 antenna). But at the same location I have a way less speed and worse connection on my PC than on iMac. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The iMac has wifi antennas all around the screen, located inside the shell, this allows for it to detect signals from all angles, which in turn give you great signal and great signal means higher wifi rates.  On the other hand, the TP-Link with only one dipole antenna will have a difficult time reading the signal from your AirPort Express.  Now, you can probably fix your issue by re-orienting your dipole antenna - This may gave you marginal improvement though.  Let me know if you gain success when you change antenna orientation.

Comment: Changing the orientation of the Airport Express may help also - get a little power extender cable and try turning the Airport Express different ways.  Use a free wireless strength graphing program in Windows 10 to demonstrate which orientation of Express and antenna work best.